# React native Redux offline API Response

Tags: react-native, redux-offline

In the redux-offline How to view my API response in the reducer. below my code I log my action in the reducer in the I can see my request data. In that reducer how to log my response data Thanks in advance

My code is here

##action.js

```
 export const sample = (requestbodydata) => ({
      
          type: 'ACTION_CALL',
          payload: { requestbodydata },
          meta: {
            offline: {
              // the network action to execute:
              effect: { url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/test/data', method: 'POST',  body: requestbodydata , headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } },
              // action to dispatch when effect succeeds:
              commit: { type: 'ACTION_CALL_COMMIT', meta: { requestbodydata } },
              // action to dispatch if network action fails permanently:
              rollback: { type: 'ACTION_CALL_ROLLBACK', meta: { requestbodydata } }
            }
          }
        });
```

##reducer.js

```
export default function reducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {        
        case 'ACTION_CALL':
        console.log('get response'+JSON.stringify(action));

        case 'ACTION_CALL_COMMIT':
        console.log('ACTION_CALL_COMMIT')
        console.log('After commit response'+JSON.stringify(action));

        case 'ACTION_CALL_ROLLBACK':
        console.log('ACTION_CALL_ROLLBACK')
          
            
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

##store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { offline } from '@redux-offline/redux-offline';
import offlineConfig from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/defaults';
import reducer from './reducer';
const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    {},
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        offline(offlineConfig)
    )
);

export default store;
```

Comment: please post some code, i don't understand your situation or the question.

Comment: @Macromeda i made a request to api by redux-offline.i want log the response of the api

Comment: no one can help you unless you post relevant parts of your code here.

Comment: i add the code in question section

Comment: @SATEESH P 
Did you solve this? If so, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/issues/63 mentions that the commit automatically gets its action.payload set to the response of the effect.

Perhaps that could be used as the following:

```
case ACTION_CALL_COMMIT: 
  console.log(action.payload);
```